# Add column to admin view of Page, Posts and Media

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a column which displays the users roles in pages /posts

This is my code:

```
$this->My_displays= array(x=> 'text','y'=> 'text2');

add_filter('manage_users_columns', array(&$this,'myusers'));    
add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  array(&$this,'function_column'), 10, 3);
add_filter( 'group_user_sortable_columns', array(&$this,'column_sortable' ));
add_filter( 'request', array(&$this,'column_orderby' ));

//Posts 
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', array(&$this,'myusers'));    
add_action('manage_posts_column_column',  'function_column', 10, 3);

//Pages
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', array(&$this,'myusers'));    
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column',  array(&$this,'function_column'), 10, 3);

//Media
add_filter( 'manage_media_columns',  array(&$this,'myusers'));
add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', array(&$this,'function_column'), 10, 3);   

function myusers($columns) {
    $columns['myusers'] = __('Views', 'myusers');
    return $columns;
}

function function_column( $value, $columnz, $ids ) {
    if ( 'myusers' != $columnze )
       return $value;
    $vars = get_user_meta($ids, 'myusers', TRUE);
    return $this->My_displays[$vars];
}
```

In Users it works fine but not in Pages and Media.

Comment: Why are you using `$columns`, `$columnz` and `$columnze`? It's easier to write all the code in English and use standard/normal function and variable names. Too much translation creativity ends like this ;)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `manage_users_columns` takes different parameters than the other `manage_*`'s.

For Users:

```
function user_column_callback( $return_value, $column_name, $user_id )
```

And for the others:

```
function posts_types_callback( $column_name, $post_id )
```

You have to create a two callbacks. And use `$post_id` to grab the post/page/media author.

Answer (score 0):

@brasofilo thank you for your reply, I did this

```
function posts_types_callback( $column_name, $post_id ) 
{   
if ($column_name == 'myusers') {  
            $Var = get_post_meta($post_id, ' myusers ', TRUE);
            return $this-> My_displays [$Var];
}
$this->My_displays= array(x=> 'text','y'=> 'text2');
```

In Users it works fine it displays text if text is checked else text2!